# How do I include class TDCollateJSon in my my code?

Tags: android, couchbase, touchdb

I have just migrated our Android project from TouchDB to CouchBase Lite.  The code compiles but when I run it I get the following error:

I have just migrated our Android project from TouchDB to CouchBase Lite.  The code compiles but when I run it I get the following error:

```
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager I/dalvikvm: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class Lcom/couchbase/touchdb/TDCollateJSON; v=0x0
2396-2415/com.example.android.manager D/chromium: Unknown chromium error: -324
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/touchdb/TDCollateJSON
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at com.couchbase.cblite.CBLDatabase.open(CBLDatabase.java:224)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at com.couchbase.cblite.router.CBLRouter.openDB(CBLRouter.java:213)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at com.couchbase.cblite.router.CBLRouter.start(CBLRouter.java:295)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at com.couchbase.cblite.listener.CBLHTTPServlet.service(CBLHTTPServlet.java:108)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at Acme.Serve.Serve$ServeConnection.runServlet(Serve.java:2347)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at Acme.Serve.Serve$ServeConnection.parseRequest(Serve.java:2266)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at Acme.Serve.Serve$ServeConnection.run(Serve.java:2056)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at Acme.Utils$ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(Utils.java:1223)
2396-2456/com.example.android.manager W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'm guessing that I have a dependency problem, but where?  I am using Gradle and Maven dependencies for CouchBase Lite.

I'm guessing that I have a dependency problem, but where?  I am using Gradle and Maven dependencies for CouchBase Lite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to follow these additional steps:

Download [td_collator_so.jar](http://cl.ly/Pr1r/td_collator_so.jar) into the newly created libs directory.

Use the following dependencies to the top-level of the build.gradle file (not under the buildscript section).

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'td_collator_so.jar')  // hack to add .so objects (bit.ly/17pUlJ1)
    ...

}
```

(This is from [Getting Started](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/wiki/Getting-Started) in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.englishtown:vertx-mod-couchbase:1.0.0-final'
}
```

Comment: I tried Gradle, Please too ;)
That's for CouchDB, not CouchBase Lite :)  But thanks!